# docker container Mysql Port outside access issue

Tags: mysql, docker, ubuntu

I've a mysql inside docker container, which is running on the server.
And I can run it normally inside the container
using

```
mysql -u root -h localhost --port=3306 -p
```

I've mapped the container 3306 to host 33069 port.

```
netstat -tnlp | grep :33069
```

the above command runed on the server shows me the following result

```
tcp6       0      0 :::33069                :::*                    LISTEN      120562/docker-proxy
```

from which it's clear that mysql is available not only for `localhost`.
However when I try to connect to the mysql from my local machine using the command

```
mysql -u root -h myAddress.com --port=33069 -p
```

I get the error
 `Can't connect to MySQL server on ...`
after timeout.
What I've missed?

Comment: have you opened 33069 port in firewall on yor HOST machine?

Comment: `sudo ufw status verbose` on the server resulted me `inactive`. As I understand there shouldn't be any problem with firewall.

Comment: vodolaz095 I've tried to check the port accessibility using https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/
this link, it shows me the port is closed.

Comment: i cannot say i understand ubuntu (i prefer Centos8 or Fedora), but it seems like either port forwarding is disabled because masquerade is disabled for physical network card, or firewall service not working, so port not opened. Try to find how open ports in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the docker run command, the container's port 3306:33069 needs to be exposed, and the docker MySql container host's server port, if the firewall is enabled for the port 33069.

Afterwards on your local pc, the port 33069 needs to be open, to communicate to MySql docker container.